# Webpack build fail: unexpected token with react-jsx file

Tags: webpack, reactjs

I'm having trouble getting Webpack to work with the following and would really appreciate some help:

my test.jsx file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

render(
  <button>OK!</button>
);
```

my webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const commonsPlugin = new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common.js');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    front_desk: './front/client/test',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  output: {
    path: 'front/public/js',
    filename: '[name].js', // Template based on keys in entry above
  },
  module: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
  },
  plugins: [commonsPlugin],
};
```

and my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
}
```

and the exact error:

```
ERROR in ./front/client/test.jsx
Module parse failed: /../front/client/test.jsx Unexpected token (5:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (5:2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set up the appropriate loaders for jsx files:

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
      presets: ['es2015']
    }
  }
]
```

[babel-loader info](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader)

Comment: Yes!! That fixed it.. now I'm onto the next set of errors. Thanks! =)